# Excel Data Validation Drop-Down using a Lookup

Tags: excel, validation, drop-down-menu, excel-formula

For some reason I can't seem to find an example for this.

I have a table with two columns, [County] and [Street].

I have another table with many columns, two of which are [County] and [Street].  On this second table, each row will already have [County] filled in, but I need to allow the user to click on the [Street] cell for each row and select (from a drop-down menu), a Street.  The Streets in the drop-down must dynamically change to only show the Streets from the first table that are included in the County on that particular row on the Second Table.

Table 1:

```
County   |  Street
-------------------
County 1 | Street 1
County 1 | Street 2
County 1 | Street 3
County 2 | Street 4
County 2 | Street 5
County 2 | Street 6
```

Table 2:

```
County   |   Street   |  Column 3  |  Column 4 
------------------------------------------------
County 1 |{Drop-down} |  --------  |  --------
County 1 |            |  --------  |  --------
County 1 |            |  --------  |  --------
County 2 |            |  --------  |  --------
County 2 |            |  --------  |  --------
County 2 |            |  --------  |  --------
```

The best conditional data validation example I can find is to use INDIRECT and point the validation to a pre-created list of Streets for each County.  That's not a good option because this data set is very large and is updated often.  I would like to use some kind of INDEX-MATCH array lookup to dynamically create the list from the original data set (Table 1), but I keep getting errors when I try to use a lookup formula.

Please keep answers to non-VBA if possible.  This workbook may need to be used in applications without VBA enabled.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: [Here](http://www.excel-university.com/create-depdendent-drop-downs-conditional-data-validation/) is a good tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the lookup table on Sheet2, sorted ascending by column A, and the drop-down on Sheet1, do this:

- Select Sheet1!B2 (the first cell where the Street drop-down will go)
- create a new named range with the Name Manager, call it "StreetList" and use this formula:

`=INDEX(Sheet2!$B:$B,MATCH(Sheet1!$A2,Sheet2!$A:$A,0)):INDEX(Sheet2!$B:$B,MATCH(Sheet1!$A2,Sheet2!$A:$A,1))`

- It is important that you select the correct cell before writing the formula, because it contains a relative reference to the cell on the left.
- apply data validation to cell Sheet1!B2 using the List option and the named range `=StreetList` as the source
- copy the data validation cell down.

When the active cell is next to "County 1", the dropdown contains only the streets for that county.

[image]

With that cell B2 selected, open the Name Manager, click the formula for StreetList and see the marching ants around the result of the formula.

[image]